# ERROR in Unexpected value 'SomeModule in C:/Users/... Please add a @NgModule annotation

Tags: angular

I have created a library in angular 9 which i want to locally use in a separate angular 8 project through npm link. But when I import a module from the library I keep getting the error - "**ERROR in Unexpected value 'SomeModule in C:/Users/... Please add a @NgModule annotation**"

My angular library public-api.ts -

```
export * from './lib/angular-library.service';
export * from './lib/angular-library.component';
export * from './lib/angular-library.module';  //this is a module MyLibModule
```

I build the library -

```
ng build library1 --watch
cd dist/library1
npm link
```

At my project root directory -

```
npm link library1
ng serve
```

My project SomeModule.module.ts -

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MyLibModule } from 'library1';   //locally importing module from library1

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        SomeComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        MyLibModule   //Getting error for this
    ],
    providers: [],
    entryComponents: []
})
```

Any idea why i keep getting the error? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the error was happening because of the dev build of the library. I tried with prod build and now it's working fine.
I changed -

```
ng build library1 --watch
```

to -

```
ng build library1 --prod --watch
```